# Sinchronize blob files from cloud to IoT Edge Blob (local)

Tags: azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-central

Please refer to the following hypothetical diagram for an IoT Edge device implementation. We want to know if there is an automated mechanism for it using the Azure IoT infrastructure.

An admin application will write several JSON configurations files associated with a specific device. Each device has a different config, and the config files are large (1Mb), so using twins is not a good solution.

We want those files stored in the cloud to be sent automatically to the target device, for it to store them in its local blob storage. The local files shall always reflect what is in the cloud, almost like a OneDrive.

**Is there any facility for this in Azure/Edge?** How we can isolate the information for each device without exposing other configurations stored in the cloud blob?

[image: Config sync]

Comment: Same question here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/678728/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Upload the BLOB to Azure storage (or anywhere, really), and set a properties.desired property containing the link+SAS token (or if you want: a hash of the contents if you want to keep the URL always the same). Your edge module will get a callback (during startup, and during runtime) that the property value has changed, and can connect to the cloud do download the configuration. No need to use LocalBlobStorage module, the config can be cached in the edge modules /tmp directory.

Comment: Sounds like a viable alternative. We will research about how to implement.